# Can an array be larger than physical memory? (e.g. can it be partially paged)

Tags: java

Let's say I have an API that provides an array of Strings for example, and this array might be larger than physical memory.

Can the JVM page part of the array and bring it from disk as I traverse it? or is an Array an "atomic" data type that can't be partially paged? I assume for a linked list the answer is much easier since any of the nodes can be paged transparently and retrieved on a page fault, but I wonder if the JVM (or if major OSs a at all) allow paging just a part of a large continuous array.

Comment: The JVM, no, but the operating system can (assuming you have a reasonably modern OS).

Comment: yes, it can, provided that your max heap size allows for that.

Comment: Is the array larger than physical memory or are the elements referenced by the array, collectively, larger than the physical memory?

Comment: @Dima thanks, so this means the max heap size can be larger than phisical memory? (which kind of makes sense I guess. this is what virtual memory is for after all, right?)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - well, good question, since I used Strings in the example, then I guess the answer is the referenced elements. which makes me realize, the actual strings can be probably paged since they the array is an array of references, right?

Comment: Yes, the heap can be larger than physical memory. Not that I think it would be a good idea ... but it is possible

Comment: A reference type array holds references to objects. A JVM typically has a configuration for what size arrays it allows you to create (technical upper bound of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: Ok, so to summarize, if your heap size is larger than physical memory, both the array itself might get paged (not sure if partially or not though) but if the array is referencing objects, then they can be paged as well. e.g. if the array is 1,000,000 referrences to some large objects, I might still be able to survive iterating over it even if the total size of them + the references is smaller than physical memory. right?

Comment: Does the API allow you to choose the type of the elements in the array? Could you store proxies to the real elements, and have the proxies load the real elements from disk and unload them as necessary?

Comment: @chiastic-security - unfortunately not

Comment: That's a pain. Even if the proxy were a subclass of the contained class? That should work unless the contained class is `final`... which it is if it's really `String`s...

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The JVM can't do this.

But you could certainly write an  implementation of `List` that would handle this transparently, storing values to disk or in a database, and retrieving them as necessary.

An operating system can page bits of memory to disk for you, but you would want to be careful about relying on this to work efficiently. Whether it will work without grinding to a halt rather depends on what you're doing. Anything that involves accessing random entries in quick succession will not cope very well with being paged out. A hash table, for instance, doesn't really perform well in this context.

Comment: It won't "kill your app completely" (aside from some "catastrophic" scenarios), as long as you reserve enough memory for the heap at jvm start.

Comment: @Dima I've changed the phrasing. But anything that involves randomly accessing elements that are largely paged out will mean constant paging in and out, which is likely to thrash the disk to the point where the system becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Agree about the risk of thrashing. My requirement is merely the ability to iterate a large array (I'm forced by the API to use it) which only works on one item at a time. ideally an iterator would have been better, but I'm relying on the OS / JVM to "lazy load" the data from disk since it's so big. so if I define a big enough heap, this might even work...